# Checkbox value not submitting

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, checkbox

**EDIT**
The form, and checkbox submits completely fine in Internet Explorer 8. In IE 10, and Chrome 34.0 it doesn't get submitted

Ok, this one has me stumped. I have a form, each form contains one question for a quiz, its possible answers, and a checkbox to select which is the correct answer.

```
<form action="/department/update_quiz_question/1/1/5" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered form-row-stripped" id="question_form_5">
  <tr id="question_5">
    <td class="col-md-4">
      <textarea name="quiz_question" class="form-control" rows="4">What letter precedes B?</textarea>
    </td>

    <td class="col-md-5">
      <div class="input-group ">
        <input type="text" class="col-md-5 form-control" name="answer[]" value="A">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="correct_answer[]" value="A">
        </span>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn red btn-delete-answer" type="button" data-question-id="5" data-answer="A"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td class="col-md-3">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm blue btn-add-answer-existing" data-question-id="5">Add Answer</a> 
      <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm green btn-update-question" data-question-id="5">Update</a> 
      <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm red btn-delete-question" data-question-id="5">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, it goes to a Codeigniter method which only contains:

```
print_r($_POST);
var_dump($this->input->post('correct_answer'));
```

As you can see, the checkbox is most certainly checked. It is also checked visually (IE there is a tick in the box).

When I submit the form, it goes through a jquery checking script. If all passes, jquery submits the form.

Just before I submit the form, I log the value of the checked checkbox, using the following:

```
console.log($(".input-group input[name^='correct_answer']:checked").val());
```

Which, as you would expect, outputs `A`, or whichever answer is ticked. So I know for certain the checkbox is ticked.

However, Codeigniter outputs the following:

```
Array ( [quiz_question] => What letter precedes A? [answer] => Array ( [0] => A ) )
bool(false)
```

The `array` is from the raw `$_POST` data. `bool(false)` is outputted from `$this->input->post('correct_answer');`.

As you can see, the checkbox value for `correct_answer` is not even displaying in raw `$_POST` data.

I can't understand what I've done wrong. I have an identical form when I create a new question, and that works perfectly fine.

Can anyone see any obvious mistakes? Or am I doing something wrong? 
Many thanks

**EDIT**

This is what I've tried so far:

- Removing all the span elements around the checkbox, leaving just the text input and the checkbox input - Still not checkbox value in the post data
- removed the square brackets around the checkbox name - no post data
- renamed the checkbox name, no post data
- Submitted the form straight away instead of passing through a jquery check first, no post data
- Changed it from a checkbox to a radio button - no post data
- **changed it from checkbox to text, - works, doesnt work when its a radio or checkbox**

Comment: Why the name is correct_answer[] instead of correct_answer?

Comment: I've tried both. Originally it was correct_answer[] because it was a checkbox, then i removed the square brackets to test it, with the same results. Even when I removed the square brackets, and change the type to radio, it doesn't get posted. However, when I check the type to `text`, it gets submitted fine. For some reason, checkboxes and radios aren't submitting

Comment: Did you have checked the CheckBox? From PHP Side, you check if checked (isset($_POST['correct_answer'])). If not Post is send, you assume not checked.

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid – you can not have a `form` element as child of `table`. Either put the whole table into the form, or the whole form inside a `td` element – these are your _only_ two options. (And different error correction algorithms for faulty HTML most likely explain why you see your current code working in a certain browser, but not in others.)

Comment: @CBroe That was it! Just replaced the table with divs and it works perfectly. I cant believe it! Very odd behaviour how its just checkbox and radios that aren't submitted! If you want to post it as an answer I'll gladly accept :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML code is invalid – you can not have a `form` element as child of `table`.

Either put the whole table into the form, or the whole form inside a `td` element – these are your only two options.¹

Different error correction algorithms for faulty HTML most likely explain why you see your current code working in a certain browser, but not in others.

---

¹ Well, if you want to stick to a table anyway – as you said in comments, moving away from using a table resolved that structural issue as well.